# What was the sita nam mahima in lomash samhita?

Tags: sita

1sita nam mahima
Sita nam mahima in lomash samhita
I couldn't find nam mahima of mata Sita

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.